# background transfer count windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, file-transfer

I'm to download files using Background Transfer Service for WP7 but the problem is sometimes my app crash for still unknown reasons for me and when i try to launch it again it just crash again with the following error.

> System.UriFormatException was unhandled   Message=Invalid URI: The
>   format of the URI could not be determined.   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BtsApi.QueryBackgroundTransferRequestTransferParameters(BtsRequestHandle
>   requestHandle)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferRequest..ctor(BtsRequestHandle
>   requestHandle, String requestId, RequestStatus requestStatus)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferService.BackgroundTransferRequestsEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at Transffr.MainPage.InitialTansferStatusCheck()    at
>   Transffr.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object
>   content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator,
>   PhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, PhoneApplicationPage
>   newContentPage)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject
>   content, NavigationMode mode)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback
>   userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(Object
>   args)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)    at
>   System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority)    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object
>   context)    at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[]
>   args)    at
>   System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr
>   pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam&
>   pResult)

which i don't understand because is in this line of code:

```
if (TransferListBox.Items.Count > 0)
{
   //Some code here
}
```

And i'm trying to count list items why does it tells me invalid URI?

And always crash using a valid Absolute URL.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PS. I took microsoft sdkbackgroundtransfer sample. Sorry my bad english.

Comment: For testing purpose i'm using this address: http://appldnld.apple.com/iTunes10/041-6241.20120611.Aaw34/iTunes64Setup.exe but sometimes it crash when i'm downloading a file inside a home network (ex http://192.168.1.101:8080/Somefile.mp3) and profiling doesn't show any memory leaks. The top memory consumption has been 42 MB when i'm downloading 90MB files.

Comment: I think i figure it out. Two parts error. First when adding a background requests there is an error when you use Uri.EscapeUriString() more info in this post link. Second i wasn't removing background transfer requests properly. Since i did this two things i haven't got any errors.

Comment: My bad the error still shows randomly. I just can't figure it out the reason.

Comment: Debugging I think i found what the problem might be. It seems background requests are not being remove for some reason. I'll post results as soon as i could fix it.

Comment: hi, in your error you've "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" it's probably a link ( image? file? ) is bad formatting. Don't forgot to explain tour problem if you find it :)